Data is not saved to database. Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}
My problem is about implementation of Firebase in android app. I have followed all steps told in the tutorials but I still cannot figure out why data is not saved to the firestore. I am aware of the fact that in this website people have come up with similar problems as mine but none helped me to solve my problem. Despite checking everything (Internet connection, rules etc), I could not solve the issue. I would be gratefull, if someone would suggest a different solution. Here are all details about the problem.
Error:
2024-05-31 15:37:19.251  8739-8739  Firestore               com.example.project2                 D  Firestore initialized successfully
2024-05-31 15:37:19.251  8739-8739  Firestore               com.example.project2                 D  Data to be saved: {Message=Sample Message, Title=Sample Title}
2024-05-31 15:37:19.297  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [FirestoreClient]: Initializing. user=null
2024-05-31 15:37:19.514  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [Persistence]: Starting transaction: build overlays
2024-05-31 15:37:19.518  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [Persistence]: Starting transaction: Start IndexManager
2024-05-31 15:37:19.523  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [Persistence]: Starting transaction: Start MutationQueue
2024-05-31 15:37:19.630  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [Persistence]: Starting transaction: Locally write mutations
2024-05-31 15:37:19.752  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [Persistence]: Starting transaction: notifyLocalViewChanges
2024-05-31 15:37:19.788  8739-8775  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [GrpcCallProvider]: Channel successfully reset.
2024-05-31 15:37:19.794  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [GrpcCallProvider]: Current gRPC connectivity state: IDLE
2024-05-31 15:37:19.817  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [WriteStream]: (ec142a2) Stream is open
2024-05-31 15:37:19.832  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [WriteStream]: (ec142a2) Stream sending: # com.google.firestore.v1.WriteRequest@d5b69189
                                                                                                    database: "projects/project2-1605c/databases/(default)"
2024-05-31 15:37:19.978  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [GrpcCallProvider]: Current gRPC connectivity state: CONNECTING
2024-05-31 15:37:19.978  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [GrpcCallProvider]: Setting the connectivityAttemptTimer
2024-05-31 15:37:34.633  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [Persistence]: Starting transaction: Backfill Indexes
2024-05-31 15:37:34.634  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [IndexBackfiller]: Documents written: 0
2024-05-31 15:37:34.981  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [GrpcCallProvider]: connectivityAttemptTimer elapsed. Resetting the channel.
2024-05-31 15:37:34.982  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [GrpcCallProvider]: Clearing the connectivityAttemptTimer
2024-05-31 15:37:34.996  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [GrpcCallProvider]: Current gRPC connectivity state: SHUTDOWN
2024-05-31 15:37:34.998  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 W  (25.0.0) [WriteStream]: (ec142a2) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Channel shutdownNow invoked, cause=null}.
2024-05-31 15:37:35.035  8739-8775  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [GrpcCallProvider]: Channel successfully reset.
2024-05-31 15:37:35.045  8739-8774  Firestore               com.example.project2                 I  (25.0.0) [GrpcCallProvider]: Current gRPC connectivity state: IDLE

MainActivity.class
package com.example.project2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Firestore";
    private FirebaseFirestore db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseFirestore.setLoggingEnabled(true);

        try {
            db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            Log.d(TAG, "Firestore initialized successfully");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error initializing Firestore", e);
        }

        saveData();


    }

    private void saveData() {
        Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
        data.put("Title", "Sample Title");
        data.put("Message", "Sample Message");

        Log.d(TAG, "Data to be saved: " + data);

        db.collection("Journal").document("My first message")
                .set(data)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Data successfully saved");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message successfully sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Error saving data", e);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message could not be sent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }
}

Manifest.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.project2">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Project2"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

build.gradle
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.project2'
    compileSdk 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.project2"
        minSdk 30
        targetSdk 34
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform(libs.firebase.bom)
    implementation libs.okhttp
    implementation libs.appcompat // Example version, update to the latest
    implementation libs.firebase.firestore.v2471 // Example version, update to the latest
    implementation libs.appcompat
    implementation libs.material
    implementation libs.activity
    implementation libs.constraintlayout
    implementation libs.firebase.firestore
    implementation libs.firebase.core
    testImplementation libs.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.ext.junit
    androidTestImplementation libs.espresso.core
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


build.gradle(Project)
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.2'
        classpath libs.google.services.v442
        classpath libs.google.services
        classpath libs.gradle // Use the latest version
        classpath libs.google.services.v4314 // Use the latest version
    }
}// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
}

I just want to save a couple of simple data to be saved to database in firestore.

Is any of the onSuccess or onFailure even triggered?

Nope, there was no message in logcat for any of them.

Have you tried to redownload the google-services.json file?

Yes I did. But it still did not help. First, I did it automatically with help of android studio. Then I did it manually. Both gave the same result.
